# Positioning of yaaleh veyavo

Tags: tefilla, blessing, yaaleh-veyavoh

Why is "yaaleh veyavoh" after the blessing of רצה in 18 on normal days ? Additionally why is its postion changed during the yom tov tefilot ?

Comment: I don't have a source for this but it seems to me that yale v'yavo is hodaa and during chol this is the beginning of hodaa in the amida but during yontiff there aren't bakashos so it fits in better in the flow of the amida for those times elsewhere